# Invalid Date from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching a document from firestore and I could already show it in the console too. This is what the data shows:

```
displayName: "Person1"
items:
  itemAcquired: t {seconds: 1631084326, nanoseconds: 617000000}
  itemName: "Book1"

[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I tried displaying the `itemAcquired` in the screen but it display an "Invalid Date":

```
 <ListItem>
     <Typography>Item Acquired At : </Typography>
          <ListItemText
               primary={new Date(user.items?.itemAcquired).toLocaleDateString()}
             />
           </ListItem>
```

Comment: `primary={new Date(user.items?.itemAcquired.t.seconds*1e3).toLocaleDateString()}`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')"

Comment: I suspect, some of your objects won't have `itemAcquired` or subsequent `t` property, so use optional chaining `?.` all the way through.

Comment: Also, consider posting ***properly notated*** object for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Date doesn't know about firestore timeStamp object, you can use toDate() function along with toDateString()

```
const date = itemAcquired.toDate().toDateString()
```

Also you can try

```
new Date(temAcquired.seconds * 1000).toUTCString()
```